# Handle duplication error of mongoDb in celery

Tags: mongodb, celery, amazon-sqs, bulkinsert

I Am writing messages into an AWS SQS Queue which should be processes by celery. In celery the json file of the filename is downloaded from an S3. Then I take batches of 20 events from the json and insert them into a mongoDB. In case the json event already exists in the mongoDB. There is automatically raised a duplication error which we handle the following way:

```
                try:
                    collection.insert_many(event_jsons, ordered=False)
                except errors.BulkWriteError as e:
                    # suppress duplicate key errors
                    panic_list = list(filter(lambda x: x['code'] != 11000, e.details['writeErrors']))
                    duplicates = list(filter(lambda x: x['code'] == 11000, e.details['writeErrors']))
                    if len(panic_list) > 0:
                        print(f"these are not duplicate errors {panic_list}")
                        raise Exception(f"Bulk error: {e}")
                    elif len(duplicates) > 0:
                        print(f"{len(duplicates)} duplicate errors fetched")
                    else:
                        pass
                except Exception as ex:
                    logger.error("problem with inserting to mongo database")
                    raise Exception(f"problem with inserting to mongo database")
```

Now all messages are processed at least once but there are still messages in the queue which are going to be processed more often. From the loggings I assume that jsons with duplicated were sending back to the Queue. Those were processed again and the queue gets emptier. However this consumes a lot of time since this procession is not necessary anymore. Is there a way such that duplicate errors are not handled as errors and thus not sent back to the Queue?

I would like to have a solution that only insert non-duplicate json-events of a batch but does not forces the message back to the SQS Queue in case there is only a duplicate error. One way I tried was to check the json for duplicates before adding them to the mongoDB and thus only json-events which were no duplicates were inserted into the mongo. This worked, however it also consumes a lot of time and I was wondering if there is way to handle this problem in the exception handling. Any help ist appriciated.